# Gestión de hilos java 1.7

Tags: java, hilos

Buenas no sé muy bien como funcionan los hilos dado que no los he usado demasiado pero quería saber si se podría hacer un hilo genérico para hacer las siguientes acciones. ¿Se puede hacer?

```
public class MiHilo extends Thread{

// boolean que pondremos a false cuando queramos parar el hilo
   private boolean continuar = true;

   // metodo para poner el boolean a false.
   public void detenElHilo()
   {
      continuar=false;
   }

   // Metodo del hilo
   public void run()
   {
      // mientras continuar ...
      while (continuar)
      {
         System.out.println("metodo");//esto es lo que quiero que sea modificable
      } 
   } 
}
```

Esto es otra clase...

```
MiHiloBO hilo = new MiHiloBO();
MiHiloBO hilo2 = new MiHiloBO();
MiHiloBO hilo3 = new MiHiloBO();
hilo.run();

//Este run quiero que haga por ejemplo un metodo por ejemplo de un objeto a

variable1=a.find();

hilo2.run();

//Este run quiero que haga por ejemplo un metodo por ejemplo de un objeto b

variable2=b.find();
```

Comment: creo que son dos preguntas en una, además preguntar si es posible es algo que depende de la opinión, generalmente alguien que ya lo ha hecho te dirá que sí, y alguien que no lo ha hecho te dirá que no

Comment: No veo nada en particular ni genérico en ese Thread. Por otro lado veo un problema potencial en el bucle while. En este caso no lo vas a notar por System.out.println() llama a una función de E/S que libera la CPU.  Pero si en lugar de eso tuvieras un cálculo aritmético, como calcular una serie por ejemplo, es probable que el Thread no libere la cpu y no corran los otros Threads dando la sensación de que se colgó la máquina. Esto lo podés evitar con un Thread sleep cada x bucles

Comment: Hola Ruslan, lo que no sé es si se puede hacer por eso pregunto y si alguien lo ha hecho pues que me diga como , por eso pregunto.

Comment: Hola Juan, si es una funcion muy simple, es solo un ejemplo a lo que me refiero es si se puede hacer un método en un hilo que por ejemplo con hilo1 hagas hilo1.metodoGenerico(le paso mi metodo A y ejecute ese metodo A) hilo2.metodoGenerico (le paso mi metodo B y ejecute ese metodo B)

Answer (score 0):

El propósito de los hilos es que pueden ejecutarse varios simultáneamente. Si requieres que varias cosas se estén ejecutando a la vez es cuando generalmente usamos hilos.

Es importante que sincronices los métodos, porque si estás usando hilos un hilo pudiera invocar a otro y pudiera haber colisiones. Así como lo muestras yo cambiaría:

```
public class MiHilo extends Thread{
    private boolean continuar = true;

    /**
     como este método es público, otro hilo lo puede invocar
    **/
    public synchronized void detenElHilo()
    {
      continuar=false;
    }
    public synchronized boolean puedeContinuar() 
    {
      return continuar;
    }
    public void run()
    {
     // mientras continuar ...
     while (puedeContinuar())
     {
     System.out.println("metodo");//esto es lo que quiero que sea modificable
      } 
    }  
}
```

Comment: Hola Alberto, 
 si buena aclaración lo de los métodos synchronized , pero me interesa más lo que le he puesto en el comentario a Juan

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que le comentas a Juan. Creo que si quieres una mejor respuesta necesitas formular una pregunta más clara. Saludos

Comment: Hola , intento explicarme mejor: los hilos tienen un método run() que ejecuta un código (el que tiene ese método run). Quería saber si se podría hacer algo como miHilo.miMetodo1() , miHilo.miMetodo2() , ya sean Metodo1 y Metodo2 dentro del run o en cualquier otro lado. Lo que no quería era tener que implementar un método run de miHilo1 que ejecute una cosa , crear otro miHilo2 para implementar otro método run que ejecute otra cosa, es decir crear una clase sola miHilo si es posible

Comment: Puedes usar parámetros para que un método invoque a otro método dependiendo de esos. Pero necesitas poner más código para poder darte mejores opciones. De momento mi respuesta es que sí se puede.